# How to display strings found in list, which is equal or contains part equal to searching input

Tags: c#, list, contains

if `List` content is:

```
0. line one
1. line two
2. line three
3. line four
```

and input string to search in list is:

```
string str = "three";
```

this way `if (List.Contains(str))`  it is not equal to any of exist string in list, and search  result is `False`. Same result if I search  by equals for example to get index of equal found string: `int index = List.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(str));`

but this way `if (List.Any(str.Contains))` I got `True` result for search of input `three` because some string in list contains this input as part of string or word in string.

Question is how to properly get same result as with `(List.Any(str.Contains))` but also to get this string as any other equal or with equal part exist in list to display. Find `line three` with input `three` and display `line three` string taken from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `List.Any(str.Contains)` will not work in your case. It checks whether there is any line which is contained in the `str`. You need to check the opposite thing - whether there are lines which contain `str`:

```
var lines = List.Where(line => line.Contains(str));
```

You can use `lines.Any()` if you want to check if any line matched given word. Note that you can put lines to list if you want to avoid this query run twice. You also can use `FindAll` method of `List<T>` class. In this case, all matched lines will be returned as list:

```
var lines = List.FindAll(line => line.Contains(str));
```

Comment: Hello, this is the answer, but I got question, I got equal result with `FindAll` and `Where` for list `var List = new List<string> { "line one", "line two", "line three", "line four", "row three", "linethree", "three" };` result which is  `line three, row three, linethree, three`, can't completely get what is a  difference? Also what is a case of using  `lines.Any()` in this case if both gives me line matched given word?

Comment: @LadO `FindAll` gives you a list. `Where` gives you an `IEnumerable<string>`. If you are going to enumerate results once, then `Where` is better. But if you are going to check if there is any results before enumerating them, then `FindAll` might be better way, because it will not run query two times